# Как получить доступ из вложенного объекта к главному

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть главное окно приложения `BankSystem`

```
#include "session.h"
#include "registration.h"
#include "login.h"

class BankSystem : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    BankSystem(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~BankSystem();

    Login* getLogin();

private:
    Ui::BankSystem *ui;

    Login *login;
    Registration *registration;
    Session* _currentSession;

};
```

Есть указатель на класс `Login`. При запуске приложения первым запускается окно входа, т.е. `Login` и, если авторизация прошла успешна, я должен засетать текущую сессию. У меня стоит слот, который отлавливает событие нажатия на кнопку `Войти`. И тут возникает проблема, как из этого слота засетать текущую сессию? Или как изменить логику, чтобы такая операция стала возможной?

```
#include "banksystem.h"

BankSystem::BankSystem(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::BankSystem)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    login = new Login();

}
```

Класс `Login`

```
class Login : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Login();

private slots:

    void on_loginButton_clicked();

    void on_registrationButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Login *ui;
};
```

```
#include "login.h"

void Login::on_loginButton_clicked()
{
    if (ui->loginSection->text().isEmpty()
            || ui->passwordSection->text().isEmpty())
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Необходимо ввести логин и пароль!");
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Icon::Information);
        msgBox.exec();
        return;
    }

    QString login = ui->loginSection->text();
    QString password = ui->passwordSection->text();

    try {
        // Вот тут мне нужно засетать сессию
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        qDebug() << e.what();
    }

}
```

Comment: А что сейчас мешает запустить сессию?

Comment: Я не могу по сути дотянуться до поля 'Session' из слота нажатия кнопки.

Comment: Передайте указатели на нужные поля в конструктор Login, и запомните их.

Comment: Просто в таком случае мне нужно создавать в классе `Login` поле: двойной указатель на `Session`.  Будет ли в таком случае решение нормальным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам класс логин нужен на один раз, так зачем его вообще создавать через указатель?
Лучше создавать и вызывать в модальном режиме в локальной памяти, для этого надо использовать `QEventLoop`:

```
class Login ... {
public:
    Login() {
        isLogged = false;
        connect(ui->buttonOk, Login::yes, [=]() {
            isLogged = true;
            _loop.quit();
        });
    }

    bool exec() {
        _loop.exec();
        return _isLogged;
    }
    QEventLoop _loop;
    bool _isLogged;
}
```

Теперь в main.cpp:

```
... main() {
    ...

    Login login;
    bool isLogged = login.exec();

    // Или, если надо дать пользователю шанс исправить ввод:
    while(isLogged = login.exec()) {
        login.setErrorMessage("Попробуйте еще раз!");
    }
    // Можно ограничить количество попыток и так далее
    // Кроме того, этот while лучше перенести внутрь exec() и 
    // там уже реализовать необходимую логику, 
    // но это вопрос вашей архитектуры

    if( _isLooged ) {
        BankSystem w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Теперь видно, что сессию, например, можно стартонуть прямо из конструктора главного окна приложения:

```
class BankSystem : ... {
    ...
public:
    BankSystem() {
        _session->start();
    }
}
```

А можно, если нужно проверять состояние сессии, сделать отдельный метод:

```
class BankSystem {
    void sessionStart() {
        if( !_session->start() ) {
            // Сессия не запустилась, надо что-то делать 
        }
    }
}
```

Я рекомендую вам сделать класс сессии синглтоном, так как обычно сессией управляет один объект, а сверять и изменять ее состояние вероятно понадобится из разных функций и методов, разной степени вложенности:

```
class Session {
public:
    static Session& instance() {
        return self == null? self = new Session(): self;
    }
private:
    Session* self;  
}
```

Теперь в любом месте программы, в любом методе:

```
Session::instance().<какая-то функция>
```

И не надо будет думать о бесконечных вызовах и коннектов

Comment: А если пользователь решит выйти с аккаунта? Мне ему снова нужно будет показать окно `Login`, поэтому я его и сделал с помощью указателя.

Comment: И вы, наверное, правы. В данном случае сессию сделать как синглтон будет наилучшим вариантом, чтобы получать к ней доступ из любой точки программы.

Answer (score 2):

1) Создаем в классе `Login` сигнал `loginOk`

```
signals:
    void loginOk();
```

2) Высылаем сигнал при успехе в `Login::on_loginButton_clicked()`:

```
void Login::on_loginButton_clicked()
{
...
   emit loginOk();
...
}
```

3) Создаем слот `BankSystem::onLoginOk()`:

```
public slots:
    void onLoginOk();
```

4) В котором и "сетим" сессию:

```
void BankSystem::onLoginOk()
{
...
    session->set(true); //не знаю, как у вас
    //опционально удаляем сендер с помощью deleteLater()
...
}
```

5) Соединяем сигнал и слот:

```
connect(login, &Login::loginOk, bankSystem, &BankSystem::onLoginOk);
```

6) Радуемся работе программы

Такой подход наиболее каноничен, православен и кошерен с точки зрения **QT**. Соединив объекты один раз, больше не надо заботится об их взаимодействии и взаимных вызовах, каждый объект будет жить своей автономной жизнью, а взаимодействие будет происходить автоматически. К тому же, не требуется использовать указатель на `Login` в качестве члена `BankSystem`. Таким же способом можно соединить `Registration` и `Login`.

Замечу, хоть и не относится к вопросу: Если требуется более-менее сложная логика логинга, сессий и регистрации, я бы выделил отдельные классы для логинга, сессии, креденциалов и регистрации и для соответсвующих окон логинга и регистрации, вместо вкладывать логику в виджетные классы. Для простой проверки в стиле `if (password == "iloveu")` - сойдет